# CSS/HTML overlaying images with text?

Tags: html, css

I've scripted a site with some text and an image in html and css, but I don't know how to overlay the image with it (How to overlay the image with the text).

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="de">
<head>
    <title>SirMarkypus | Homepage</title>
    <link href="homepage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="headline1">Willkommen auf dem SirMarkypus-Server!</h1>
    <img id="backgrounder1" src="img/backgrounder.png" alt="SirMarkypus-
Backgrounder">
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background: gray;
}
#backgrounder1 {
position: absolute;
top: -60px;
width: 1910px;
height: 720px;
}

#headline1 {
position: relative;
margin: 0px;
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
font-family: "Verdana";
font-size: 48px;

color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Why not use background-image on H1 itself?

Comment: @Nawed Khan How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the CSS, in `#headline1` add the property `z-index: 9999;` and change it's `position` to `absolute`

What `z-index` does is to push a div above/below the other. So the div with `z-index: 1` is lower that a div with `z-index: 10`

Answer (score 0):

I think that overlying the image and the H1 will get you troubles in the future, I suggest to use the image as a background of the `#headline1` (or of your `body` if that is what you need).

You can accomplish this by using CSS:

```
background-image: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-UbfRzKJqnyk/UJyT60Mm7eI/AAAAAAAADFs/bLcANzIsYfs/s1600/pattern_of_holes-dark_background_pattern.jpg);
```

this is the result (run the code snippet):

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}
#backgrounder1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -60px;
  width: 1910px;
  height: 720px;
}

#headline1 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Verdana";
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #000;
  background-image: url('http://freedesignfile.com/upload/2013/09/Metal-background-5.jpg');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="de">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="headline1">Willkommen auf dem SirMarkypus-Server!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give z-index to your h1 ;
for example :

```
h1 {
  z-index: 1040;
}
```

You can see at here :
JS-FIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/60c5napb/